Has any Guru/scripture explained why god actually descends to the earth when he can accomplish whatever he wants from his heavenly abode?
I remember a religious discourse (I think it was by Velukkudi Krishnan Swamigal) in which the speaker said Vishnu can set Dharma right on earth from Vaikuntha - but I forgot the reasons he said why God actually descends to the earth.
The Gita says the descent of God happens to remove Adharma - my question why Vishnu does not protect Dharma on the earth from Vaikuntha itself.

I can ask you refer to the text “Sri Ramakrishna and his divine play”, and any such books of the Ramakrishna organisation.
The answers given by the monastic order says - god out of his compassion for the earthly beings take birth in this human world and suffers through the misery of the human beings . By doing this he/she is able to understand our pain and show us a way to the infinite god or Brahman and letting us free from all the bondage.
Also god can do anything by his mere thinking but chooses not to as he wants us to get all the experiences of the mortal life and make us strong enough to receive spiritual powers, whose importance won’t be understood if not worked hard for it.
